# Key Trigger action listener

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I have a calculator program that works by clicking a button - appending the text to a string and later is passed and converted into a double to do the calc.

```
but1.addActionListener(this);
if (source==but1) // Number buttons shows the text to display
        {
            text.append("1");
}

public double number_convert() // Converts the string back to double
    {

        double num1;
        String s;
        s = text.getText();
        num1 = Double.parseDouble(s); // creating a double from the string value.   
        return num1; //returns value 
    }
```

I need to run the `ActionListener` for the button by keyboard key. Any ideas how to do this?

Everything works on the calculator I just need a way to run the buttons when a keyboard key is pressed.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would be to use a combination of `Action`s and Key Bindings API.  See [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) and [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details

```
NumberAction action = new NumberAction(1);
JButton btn = new JButton(action);
InputMap im = btn.getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
ActionMap am = btn.getActionMap();

im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_1, 0), "Number1");
am.put("Number1", action);
```

And a general example `Action`...

```
public class NumberAction extends AbstractAction {

    private int number;

    public NumberAction(int number) {
        this.number = number;
        putValue(NAME, Integer.toString(number));
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Deal with the number...
    }
}
```

The `Action` can be used for both the button AND the key binding, making them quite flexible...